# Friendly Switch with a Medium and Large (or more) characters

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, movement

The [Friendly Switch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/friendly-switch/) feat says :

> As part of your movement or as a 5-foot-step, you can move into the space occupied by an ally of your size or smaller, which displaces the ally into the space you just left. Your ally must be willing and able to move and able to occupy the space you were in.

If a large (or taller) character moves into the space of a willing medium size ally, how does it work ? Is the Medium character "pushed" two (or more, depending on the size) cases away ? Or does it mean that in this situation, the medium character doesn't fulfill the requirements about being able to move and to occupy the space of the ally ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the term *space* is the total (often cubic) area a creature occupies (q.v. [Space, Reach, & Threatened Area Templates](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/) on Creature Sizes and [Monster Entry Format](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-entry-format/) on Space/Reach). However, the feat [Friendly Switch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/friendly-switch/) synonymizes *space* with a location on the battlefield. (Such locations are sometimes called *squares*.)

This reader recommends not taking absolutely literally the benefit of the feat Friendly Switch as then the feat becomes wholly nonfunctional: a creature never *exits* its *space* (i.e. the feat's benefit using the phrase "the *space* you just left" (emphasis mine)). Instead, a creature essentially *is* its space, *space* here defining how many squares a creature occupies. So that the feat's benefit makes sense, this reader recommends a house rule that changes the Friendly Switch feat's benefit to the following:

> As part of your movement or as a 5-foot-step, you can move into a square occupied by an ally of your size or smaller, which displaces the ally into at least one square you just left. Your ally must be willing and able to move (e.g. not paralyzed) and able to occupy its new location on the battlefield normally (e.g. without squeezing).

This house rule will allow, for example, a wizard use this feat on her cat familiar and an ogre to use this feat on allied ogre, both of which were previously impossible even with a generous reading of the original feat's benefit.

This reader won't apologize for the feat's lack of clarity, but, to be fair, he will point out that the feat was originally published nearly a decade ago in [*Seeker of Secrets*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601251785) (2009) and has never been revisited.